# Remove ubuntu 14.04 from dual boot, resize partitions and reinstall

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning

When I first installed ubuntu I remove enough space from my windows partition for both ubuntu and a shared storage partition. The way that the partitions are set up, I believe my only option to make them bigger is to remove my ubuntu installation. At this point I've been having a lot of problems from messing around too much with ubuntu so reinstalling seems like a good idea anyway.

Basically I have no idea how to go about doing this. I have no need to get rid of the grub bootloader or anything like that, I would just like to make sure I know how to safely do this without damaging my storage partition or windows installation. Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: add your gparted screenshot..

Comment: the internet is currently not working on my ubuntu installation and when I booted in I realized I don't have gparted installed so I just grabbed a shot from disks, let me know if there's any info thats not on here that would be useful

Comment: Whenever you change partitions there's always a small chance of data loss, to be perfectly safe and go "by the book" you should really backup any important data first. That could give the opportunity to move old data off of your HD and onto some backup medium, freeing up more space on your HD too.

Comment: apparently I don't have enough reputation to post images

Comment: Would it be as simple as backing up, deleting all ubuntu related partitions and start the installation process from there then? I basically just follow guides for things like this and while I'm not opposed to trying things on my own I just get worried when messing with things that could have consequences that would take up so much of my time.

Comment: If you could post a link to the image that would be ok too, I might be able to add it to your Q, or you could try `sudo fdisk -l` and paste the text from that in a "Code Sample" from the answer/edit toolbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For re-installing Ubuntu it should be as simple as backing up & installing new.

Deleting the data from the old Ubuntu "`/`" partition may not be necessary, but it couldn't hurt. If you've got your home on a different partition you can keep that and use it with the new Ubuntu, most of your settings and things should be waiting for you in the new Ubuntu then.

That's a good way to upgrade to a newer Ubuntu release too, used to be recommended more often in the past, especially if the in-place dist-upgrade has any problems (or to avoid them in the first place).

If you wanted to completely remove Ubuntu, then erasing it's partition would do it, and could leave GRUB and edit it's menu (grub.cfg file) to remove the Ubuntu boot options. As long as the GRUB data isn't on the Ubuntu partition... But Windows is good at "fixing" booting problems for itself from a repair disk (by obliterating other boot loaders like Grub) if that were your goal.